# mysql Получить данные из двух таблиц одним запросом

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

есть три таблицы страна->регион->город где в каждой последующей есть id предыдущей, к которой та относится:

**тбл.страна**

```
id name
1  Албания
2  Уругвай
3  Вьетнам
```

**тбл.регион**

```
id name               countryid    
1  Албанский регион   1
2  Уругвайский регион 2
3  Вьетнамский регион 3
```

**тбл.город**

```
id name                regionid 
1  Албанская столица   1
2  Уругвайская столица 2
3  Вьетнамская столица 3
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как одним запросом по Id города получить id региона и страны.

Comment: смотрите про join

Comment: `select t1.*,t2.*,t3.*
    from table1 t1
    left join table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.id,
    left join table3 t3 on t3.id = t1.id
` получение всех данных с 3х таблис с одинаковым id

Comment: @InDevX текст запроса не соответствует заданному вопросу.

Comment: @Akina пока писал - не было толком понятно какая информация есть в наличии...

Comment: `select r.id, cn.id from city c left join region r on r.id = c.id, left join country cn on cn.id = c.id` как-то так, получается

Comment: InDevX риспект спасибо большое)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Лично мне нравится запросы вот такие, тут все понятно откуда что как берется:

```
SELECT 
    тбл.страна.name as `countryname`, 
    тбл.регион.name as `regionname`, 
    тбл.город.name as `cityname` 
FROM тбл.страна, тбл.регион, тбл.город 
WHERE 
    тбл.страна.id = тбл.регион.countrid 
    AND тбл.регион.id = тбл.город.regionid 
    AND тбл.город.id = какой-то город ид
```

Comment: а лично мне нравится, когда запрос можно прочитать целиком без того чтобы полчаса елозить мышкой )

Comment: @Ипатьев, новенький ещё)

Comment: да ты просто уолчара))